# Sharepoint Designer 2013 - Filter drop down menu

Tags: sharepoint, drop-down-menu, sharepoint-2013, infopath

I have a form on Sharepoint, whereby I have 2 drop-down controls.
Lets say the first one has values *"A, B and C"* to choose from.

[image]

According to the option selected in the 1st drop-down, I will have to populate the 2nd drop-down accordingly.

Is there a way to do that in Sharepoint Designer or Infopath?
The dropdown are both created similarly;
[image]

Or if I can at least filter the 2nd drop down, according to the value chosen in the 1st drop down.

I am newbie in Sharepoint dev, and need some tips on the above.

Comment: Did you figure out a solution? I am also struggeling with it.

Answer (score 1):

if I've understood you correctly, what you are trying to do is populate the 2nd dropdown list based on what is selected from the first.

Have you tried to put a filter on the 2nd drop-down, like this...?

- Open up your list form in InfoPath
- Right click on the 2nd choice field and select, 'Drop-down List Box Properties'
- Click on the button to the right of 'Entries'
- Click on 'Filter Data' button
- Click on 'Add'
- Enter the condition (i.e. 'Choice' is equal to 'Choice', or whatever the name of your 1st choice field is.)

Does that work?  (I'm assuming you aren't using a secondary data source.)